Why doesn't my HP laptop start normally and just shows a black screen while it is on?
My HP laptop works on Windows 11 and is acting weird lately. Whenever it turns off or goes to sleep and then I try to power it up again it shows the HP loading screen then the screen is on but black.
Sometimes it does turn on but I have to power it off then on again using the power button. It also shows me the blue screen with two choices either to shutdown or to choose 'advanced options'. Also my laptop did show me a message last year that a fan is not working. Does this have anything to do with that? I use this laptop only for school work. Also sometimes when it eventually turns on it goes to tablet mode by itself.

A fan not working can be problematic. You should get it serviced. It may or may not be related to the problem you reported. If no other problem haven't been reported I would suggest just updating the UEFI ("BIOS") and troubleshoot from there but knowing there's potentially a faulty fan for so long, the longer you use it the chances of having a very serious problem increase exponentially. So, again, get it service by official HP tech support.

You should get the computer serviced. If fans are failing that is a serious issue that needs to be addressed. The other symptoms indicate possible storage device issues, which also need to be addressed. Both these sets of issues are best addressed by competent computer hardware technicians, and as it seems your computer is probably relatively new, you should talk to HP support first.
